# TypeError: Failed to fetch - Problem with Javascript Asyn

Tags: javascript, api

I just start learning Javascript. I am currently learning asynchronous js. I want to build a Weather Application with AccuWeather API. But its keep throwing error in the console and it not working

Here is the error

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

In my directory. I have

> Index.html

```
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
...
        <form class="change-location my-4 text-center text-muted">
          <label for="city">Enter a location for weather information</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control p-4">
        </form>

...
  <script src="scripts/forecast.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

> app.js

```
//Select the form
const cityForm = document.querySelector('form');

//get city details & weather
const updateCity = async (city) => {

    const cityDets = await getCity(city);
    const weather = await getWeather(cityDets.key);

    //returns city and weather response
    return {
        cityDets: cityDets,
        weather: weather
    };
};

//prevent default action
cityForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault

    //trim any whitespace & get city value
    //cityForm.city.value = selection + input name + input value
    const city = cityForm.city.value.trim();

    //remove the previous entry
    cityForm.reset();

    //update the UI withcity info
    updateCity(city)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

> In my app.js

```
const key = '*****************';

const getWeather = async (id) => {

    const base = 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/';
    const query = `${id}?apikey=${key}`;
    const response = await fetch (base + query);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data[0];
}

//get city information
const getCity = async (city) => {

    //base, apikey, cityname - 
    const base = 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search';
    const query = `?apikey=${key}&q=${city}`;
    const response = await fetch(base + query);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data[0];
};
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: does you form has `name` on it's inputs?

Comment: Yes,           `<input type="text" name="city" class="form-control p-4">`

Comment: Code looks fine https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sunset-c4pwr, I bet that your request resolves with some error like 401. Can you open `base + query` in a new browser tab or how request resolves in the Network panel?

Answer (score 0):

try catching your error after the fetch call:

```js
const url = 'https://weatherapi/basepath'+key; //or whatever this is

fetch(url)
  .then(res => ...do stuff)
  .catch(err => console.log('ERROR', error)); //here
```